# new ctrl-period key sequence default in 21.10?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 21.10

I just moved up from 21.04 to 21.10. I have the 1Password extension installed in Firefox, which uses ctrl-period keystroke to launch the password manager. I've been using that since... uh... 18.10? 19.04? several years now at least with no problems between releases. But now on 21.10 ctrl-period is behaving very weird. It puts an underlined e in whatever text entry window has focus, anything I type then gets underlined, but if I hit enter the letters sometimes get jumbled up a bit, but often just the e and the underline get removed? It's really confusing... I have no idea what it's doing. This happens everywhere, terminal text editor, browser, IDE, todo list.... so I'm assuming it's some kind of system wide thing. ***What is this?* What mode have I unknowingly stumbled into?** Can I change what keys trigger it?

Comment: This was screwing me up in pycharm because it overwrote the shortcut for comment folding!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To answer the question "what is this?" and also to clear up the confusion about the underlined e you're seeing.

This is a new way to enter emoji. Here's how you use it. I was confused at first too. It's a little counter-intuitive, but you just type in the name of the emoji after ctrl-. and hit space enter like this:

ctrl-.

> e

type the name of the emoji

> eheart

hit space

> e

hit space again to cycle through more options if you want more options

> e❤️

hit enter to finish

> ❤️

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: How does it not answer? I'm telling you how to enter emoji using ctrl-.

Comment: the question actually asks a bunch of questions. I'm answering "what is this?"

I'll clarify in my answer

Comment: This is actually a great user perspective answer!

Answer (score 81):

I've ran `gsettings list-recursively | grep "<Control>"` and noticed that, two new shortcuts were added:

```
org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey ['<Control>period']
org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey ['<Control><Shift>u']
```

Not sure what that is, but must be some new emoji picker feature. It doesn't seem to be working in my environment. It's possible to unset it though:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "[]"
```

Thanks for raising this, by the way. I struggle with this new 1Passord issue for almost a week now and haven't though of checking shortcuts

Comment: aahhhh... THAT is promising.... and searching for "ibus emoji picker" tells me that a space character after the hotkey will display a menu of emoji classes... sure enough `<ctrl>-period, space` brings up that menu and dialog. When that dialog is open an "Emoji Picker" app shows up in my task bar.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was so frustrated, even I didn't know what was happening but you made my day.

Comment: See also answer by  pasman pasmański: can be changed using the tool ibus-setup

Comment: Same as through `gsettings set` it can be set to any other shortcut.

Comment: Thank you so much! Life-saver, it was messing with one of my VSCode shortcuts.

Comment: The OS should only capture keyboard shortcuts that include the Super key. All other combinations should be left for apps!

Answer (score 19):

You may change this shortcut in `ibus-setup` , tab Emoji

Comment: One day, Ubuntu/GNOME/whatever will learn to define all their shortcuts with the super key, leaving ctrl to application level. One day.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Description on how to change Ctl+. (period)]

Open a terminal and type, so navigate to **Emoji** tab and edit that configuration, check the image below

```
ibus-setup
```

Comment: This does not work for me on Ubuntu 21.10 running on Xorg.

Comment: This worked for me on Kubuntu 22.04

Comment: Best answer! Thank you very much !!

Comment: thank you! this has been bugging me locally for ages