# pressing Ctrl+. shows e

Tags: shortcut-keys

I installed the Cinnamon Desktop Environment on My `Ubuntu 21.10` OS.
After that whenever I open a text editor and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> it prints <kbd>e</kbd>. It just toggles if I press it multiple times. I tried different Desktop Environment like KDE, it behaves exactly same.
When i remove the DE and use Ubuntu as is, the problem goes away !

I am quite unsure why this is happening , bit of help on this will be really helpful,
Is there any restriction in terms of using different Desktop Environments on Ubuntu?

```
OS: Ubuntu Cinnamon 21.10 x86_64 
Kernel: 5.13.0-30-generic 
Shell: bash 5.1.8 

DE: Cinnamon 4.8.6 
WM Theme: Fluent-round-compact (Yaru 
Theme: Fluent-round-compact [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Fluent-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal
```

Comment: I was curious as it was not just with Mint, other distros had the same issue, but thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing I believe is part of a means for quickly inserting emojis with the ibus input method framework. There's some details about it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1687342/what-is-my-x11-doing-with-ctrl-period-and-how-can-i-disable-it) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372781/new-ctrl-period-key-sequence-default-in-21-10), including I think a way to disable it.

Addition :
Just for easy reference added shortcut change the process.

- Search for `IBus Preference`
- Go to `Emoji` tab
- Change the `Emoji annotation` to anything else.
- Click Apply

[image]

Comment: Normally, in GTK applications, Ctrl+. should display a window to pick an emoticon. In other applications, e.g. Firefox, it does nothing. So here something else seems to happen.

Comment: @frabjous and  @vanadium Thank you, those links do have good information, and i was able to change the default shortcut for emoji from `ibus-preference`, things seems to work out.

Comment: For me searching for `Ibus Preference` didn't bring up this dialog, but you can get to it by typing in a terminal: `ibus-setup`.

Alternatively setting an empty shortcut with `gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "[]"` also worked for me.